# Controlling placement of the edit link in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way to control the placement of the edit link for a content item that get's rendered when you're logged in?  I'm assuming this can be done using the placement.info but I'm not sure how do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with placement, just with CSS.